# Creating a configuration that will run all unit test on JVM and then start the Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, buildconfiguration

I want to add the initialization of all my unit (and eventually integration) tests before each build. I have a `Unit Tests` configuration build and the default `app` configuration build, but I could find anything that combines both of them. The closest thing I found was a `Compound` build which seemed like a good sandbox option to create a custom build -

[image]

When I tried to execute it only the app build succeeded while the unit tests one failed saying it can't be run on the emulator.

How can I configure first the unit tests to run on the JVM and than only if all succeed to run the app on the emulator / physical device?